# How to debug “SIP registration failed”?

Tags: firewall, sip

My SIP phone, which I use from Turkey with a virtual UK number, has recently stopped working with "SIP registration failed" and the supplier of the UK number has told me the times of the last registration attempts seen in their logs.

As those times are in the middle of the night (separated by 40 minutes) when we were not using the phone perhaps the phone or the box connecting it to the router automatically periodically register every 40 minutes. Does that sound likely? Or possibly there were power cuts here and it re-registered when the power came back on. We have power cuts from time to time. The IP of the box is now 192.168.0.2 which is assigned automatically. Should I set it to be a static address so it would not change after power cuts?

Anyway since then I have always got "SIP registration failed".

The same problem occurred last year but resolved itself after about a month (and the phone worked fine when I tested it within the UK). Therefore I suspect some change by my ISP (TTNET) or the underlying telecoms provider (Turk Telecom), perhaps some incompetent general (not related to me in particular!) censorship or surveillance attempt. I have asked them if they have made changes but have received no reply as yet.

I will try and check with a softphone mentioned [here](http://wiki.aa.org.uk/Category:VoIP_Phones) to rule out intermittent hardware failure.

I guess I could also try the kit at a friend's house with a different ISP.

I have not changed my firewall or router settings. According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/410964/what-are-the-possible-reasons-for-a-sip-register-failure) network debugging might help locate the problem. But although I am experienced in IT generally I am not very experienced in networks so I am asking your advice on the best way to do it. The ping appears OK as far as I can tell but the trace route below took a little while. Is that normal and how can I debug further? For example could I find the [SIP response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes)

```
PS C:\Users\Geoff> ping voiceless.aa.net.uk

Pinging voiceless.aa.net.uk [81.187.30.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 81.187.30.113: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=50
Reply from 81.187.30.113: bytes=32 time=78ms TTL=50
Reply from 81.187.30.113: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=50
Reply from 81.187.30.113: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 81.187.30.113:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 76ms, Maximum = 78ms, Average = 76ms
PS C:\Users\Geoff>

PS C:\Users\Geoff> tracert voiceless.aa.net.uk

Tracing route to voiceless.aa.net.uk [81.187.30.113]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     1 ms     4 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    18 ms     9 ms     9 ms  95.5.32.1.dynamic.ttnet.com.tr [95.5.32.1]
  3    10 ms     8 ms     9 ms  81.212.78.109.static.turktelekom.com.tr [81.212.78.109]
  4    14 ms    15 ms    14 ms  samsun-t2-1-samsun-t3-1.turktelekom.com.tr.207.212.81.in-addr.arpa [81.212.207.26]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    89 ms    77 ms    92 ms  ldn-b5-link.telia.net [213.248.104.41]
  9    82 ms   132 ms   133 ms  ldn-bb2-link.telia.net [80.91.246.114]
 10    77 ms    95 ms    95 ms  ldn-b7-link.telia.net [213.155.137.119]
 11    81 ms    86 ms    78 ms  verio-129583-ldn-b5.telia.net [213.248.100.50]
 12    84 ms    79 ms    87 ms  ae-1.r00.londen10.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.31]
 13    75 ms    74 ms    74 ms  83.217.238.94
 14    84 ms    74 ms    74 ms  a.weightless.thn.aa.net.uk [90.155.53.61]
 15    77 ms    81 ms    80 ms  a.needless.thn.aa.net.uk [81.2.80.193]
 16    77 ms    77 ms    76 ms  a.homeless.tch.aa.net.uk [217.169.11.93]
 17    75 ms   103 ms    75 ms  b.voiceless.aa.net.uk [81.187.30.113]

Trace complete.
PS C:\Users\Geoff>
```

Comment: What do you see when you use wireshark to sniff the failed connection attempts?  Wireshark will allow you to see any returned errors

Comment: I tried with a softphone and it works. So I will buy a new physical phone when I go to the UK shortly. I have not used Wireshark before so if the problem recurs with new hardware I will watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65sv-25YZio and hopefully use Wireshark to get more details of the problem. Thank you very much for your help.